# How do I separate two div tags when inserting a div tag into dojo editor

Tags: dojo

I have a problem, please help me.

I made a dialog to insert an image link with the following description into the dojo editor:

```
var img_link =   "<div id="image"><img src='test.jpg' alt=''/><div id='description'>Description of image </div></div>"

//insert image with description to editor
var ed = dijit.byId('editorId');
ed.focus();
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", img_link);
```

I am able to insert the link into the editor successfully, but the rest of the content is part of the link.  I want the second div element to be be separate from the other content. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate variables for the image you are inserting and the description:

```
var img_link = "<img id='myImage' src='test.jpg' alt=''>";
var img_desc = "<div id='description'>Description of image</div>";
```

Then insert them individually:

```
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", img_link);
ed.execCommand("inserthtml", img_desc);
```

Note that you will need to update the dijit.byId('') before inserting each element.

The outer  element that you are using to contain the image and description elements should be on your html page, not contained in the img_link variable:

Comment: thanks TedPrz, but could you tell me more about update the dijit.byId('') before inserting each element. I don't really understand what it means :D

Comment: @johnITBonuc maybe I misunderstood your question.  Are you trying to insert an image and a description into a dijit.Editor? Or into a dijit.Dialog?